# How to find minimum and maximum of points in x and y coordinates

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, bounding-box

I have a collection of points with x and y coordinates in RDD[Double, Double] format. I want to find the minimum and maximum of both latitudes and longitudes from this RDD. From the minimum and maximum values, my goal is to find the lower left and upper right coordinates of the bounding box of whole space (as shown in the image in this link).
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/48509/versions/3/previews/COMP_GEOM_TLBX/html/Bounding_box_2D_01.png

This is what I am starting with, but it says "Too many arguments for method min()"

```
val minX= points.min(p=>p(0))
val minY=points.min(p=>p(1))
val maxX=points.min(p=>p(0))
val maxY=points.max(p=>p(1))
```

I am new to Scala and please pardon me if this seems like a simple problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you meant `RDD[(Double, Double)]`. You could first convert each point into a zero-area bounding box, and then reduce all bounding boxes, combining all four values at once:

```
val boundingBox = 
  points
  .map{ case (x, y) => (x, x, y, y) }
  .reduce { case ((xl, xr, xb, xt), (yl, yr, yb, yt)) =>
    (xl min yl, xr max yr, xb min yb, xt max yt)
  }
```

The `l, r, b, t` shortcuts mean `left`, `right`, `bottom`, `top`.

Your code with `min` does not work, because `RDD.min` does not take any arguments (at least not in the first, non-implicit argument list). There also seems to be no `minBy` / `maxBy`.

Comment: Thanks. I understood the map part but please can you further explain how reduce is working to make a bounding box from all points? In particular, why do we have xb, xt, yl, and yr? And can we access the 4 values individually from this bounding box?

Comment: @user3316676 The function passed to `reduce` combines two bounding boxes `x` and `y` with lefft-right-bottom-top coordinates `(xl, xr, xb, xt)` and `(yl, yr, yb, yt)` into one big bounding box that encloses both `x` and `y`. I probably shouldn't have called the two boxes `x` and `y`, because these two names are not related to horizontal / vertical coordinates in any way. Only `l` and `r` are "horizontal", and `b` and `t` are "vertical" coordinates.